# mounting secrets as hidden file on K8s

Tags: kubernetes

I have a php app that uses a .env file to fetch Environmental Variables. All of these variables are stored on AWS Secrets Manager and fetched by EKS and stored in a K8S secret. I want to mount the secret as a .env file in the container. I am getting the error below when I run the container on K8S.

```
Error: failed to start container "php-app": Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: │
│  error during container init: error mounting "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/4aa66371-0590-403c-b81d-6bff51160fa0/volume-subpaths/envfile/php-app/0" to rootfs at "/var/www/html/.env": mount /var/lib/kubelet/pods/4aa66371-0590-403c-b81d-6bff51160fa0/volume │
│ -subpaths/envfile/php-app/0:/var/www/html/.env (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5001: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

my deployment manifest

```
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: envfile
      secret:
        secretName: php-app-secrets           
  containers:
    - name: php-app
      image: php-image:1.9
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumeMounts:
        - name: envfile
          mountPath: "/var/www/html/.env"
          readOnly: true
          subPath: ".env"
```

Any idea on how I can mount the .env file? is it even possible?

Comment: _... stored in a K8S secret_ have you double-checked there is such a key in that `Secret`? And can you successfully use it with a different `mountPath:`, like `/tmp/.env` (meaning is it just `/var/www/html/.env` that makes k8s angry)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mount the entire Secret as a single file.

If you look at, for example, the [Create a Pod that has access to the secret data through a Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#create-a-pod-that-has-access-to-the-secret-data-through-a-volume) sample setup, this mounts the entire Secret as a volume.  In that example each setting in the Secret becomes a separate file in the container.  Trying to set `subPath: .env` will try to mount only the single value from the Secret with the value `.env`.

What you can do, though, is [Configure all key-value pairs in a Secret as container environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-secret-as-container-environment-variables)

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    - name: php-app
      image: php-image:1.9
      envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: php-app-secrets
```

This will cause every value in the Secret to appear in the container directly as an environment variable; you don't need to write out a `.env` file and then load it back in.  This is exactly the same kind of environment variable as if you had run `export VARIABLE=value` in a local shell.